# Mongoose update whole Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose to make a Backbonejs driven app. Basically I have a model of exams and inside it I have an array of questions. So when the user answer a question I make a PUT on a endpoint ( using Backbonejs' model save method ) to update this array of questions ( I want to override it ).
But when I do this I receive an error.

This is my code:

```
Exam.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.body._id}, {questions: req.body.questions},   function(err, exam){
    console.info(err)
    if(err) res.end();
    res.json(req.body)
})
```

where console.info(err) outputs: 
**[TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'split']**

This is my object ( simplified ):

```
{
    exam: "First exam",
    id: 1,
   questions: [
       {
           question: "Where does babies come from?",
           answer: 1
       },
       {
           question: "What time is it?",
           answer: 3
       }
   ]
}
```

Note: When I try to update a string propertie like "exam" it updates it ok.

Does anyone has an idea of what's happening? Thanks!!

Comment: What is the type of req.body.questions? String or Array?

Answer (score 0):

I found that was a bug with the TingoDb that I was using. Thanks for the help!